# Unknown server tag 'FCKeditorV2:FCKeditor

Tags: asp.net

So i`m getting an unknown server tag for FCKeditor in my aspx page. [Here is the link to the source code](http://pastebin.com/SvQfXCd3)

Among the solutions tried:

1) `<%@ Register Assembly="FredCK.FCKeditorV2" Namespace="FredCK.FCKeditorV2" TagPrefix="FCKeditorV2" %>`

2) Checked if the dll (FredCK.FCKeditorV2.dll) was in the directory.

Firebug gives me an: 500 Internal Server Error

AND

The actual error is: Parser Error Message: Unknown server tag 'FCKeditorV2:FCKeditor'.

I have a similar page with the same code and for some reason it works and this one doesn`t.

Comment: Does the assembly `FredCK.FCKeditorV2` contain a public control `FCKeditor`?

Comment: Random aside that FCK has a newer version, CKEditor.

Comment: I`m not sure if it does or doesn`t

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're working with the same version of the .Net Framework between your test machine and final server.  It could be that your server needs to be upgraded to a new service pack.

For instance, VS2005 without a service pack will show a version of 2.0.50727.45.  SP1 will give you a version of 2.0.50727.832.